# How to take a screenshot of the content of a ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'd like to take a screenshot of whatever is inside a `ScrollViewer`, not just what is seen inside the `ViewPort`. But everything I tried so far results in completely black images or in images where only parts of the content are shown and everything else is black. I assumed that it's maybe because I didn't specify any backgrounds, but changing the background of my `Window` or my `TreeView` to `White` didn't change a thing.
Can you tell me what is wrong or how else I can take a screenshot of the full content of a `ScrollViewer`?

Here's a little sample I put together (press 'P' after the main window is shown).

The main window (just a `TreeView` in a `Window` that is too small to show the full content):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScreenshotTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="200" Width="300"
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
    <TreeView x:Name="Tree">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr" IsSelected="True" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1.1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1.2" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1.2.1"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1.3" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1.3.1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1.3.2" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Node 1.3.3" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2 - sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2.1"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2.2" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2.2.1"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2.3" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2.3.1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2.3.2" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Node 2.3.3" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

And the code behind to the window:

```
Class MainWindow

Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.Key <> Key.P Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim sv As ScrollViewer = GetFirstChildOfType(Of ScrollViewer)(Me.Tree)
    Me.CaptureScreen(sv.Content, "C:\Temp\Screenshot.png")
End Sub

Private Shared Function GetFirstChildOfType(Of T As DependencyObject)(obj As DependencyObject) As T
    Dim result As T
    Dim child As DependencyObject

    If (obj Is Nothing) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    If (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) = 0) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    For index As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj)
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, index)
        result = TryCast(child, T)

        If (result Is Nothing) Then
            result = GetFirstChildOfType(Of T)(child)
        End If

        If (result IsNot Nothing) Then
            Return result
        End If
    Next index

    Return Nothing
End Function

Private Sub CaptureScreen(source As UIElement, filename As String)
    Dim height As Double
    Dim renderHeight As Double
    Dim width As Double
    Dim renderWidth As Double
    Dim renderTarget As RenderTargetBitmap
    Dim vb As VisualBrush
    Dim dv As DrawingVisual
    Dim encoder As PngBitmapEncoder

    Try
        height = source.RenderSize.Height
        renderHeight = height
        width = source.RenderSize.Width
        renderWidth = width

        renderTarget = New RenderTargetBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(renderWidth), Convert.ToInt32(renderHeight), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
        vb = New VisualBrush(source)

        dv = New DrawingVisual

        Using dc As DrawingContext = dv.RenderOpen
            dc.DrawRectangle(vb, Nothing, New Rect(New Point(0, 0), New Point(width, height)))
        End Using

        renderTarget.Render(dv)

        encoder = New PngBitmapEncoder
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget))

        Using fs As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            encoder.Save(fs)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

I'm fine with answers in C# as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found out, that I got several things wrong.

First, I used the wrong `UIElement`. I had to take the first `StackPanel` instead of the first `ScrollViewer`.

Second, although my `Window` has the background set to white, all my controls inside `Window` doesn't have a background, that's probably why my resulting picture is black.

So, changing just one function of my code to

```
Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Dim panel As StackPanel

    If e.Key <> Key.P Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    panel = GetFirstChildOfType(Of StackPanel)(Me.Tree)
    panel.Background = Brushes.White
    panel.UpdateLayout()

    Me.CaptureScreen(panel, "C:\Temp\Screenshot.png")
End Sub
```

did the trick, now I at least get a picture with a white background and all the elements of my `TreeView`, not just the ones visible on screen.

Now I have some other problems, but that's an issue for another question.